# Drawing a GDI bitmap of variable size with StretchBlt causes Black unshrinking borders to appear

Tags: winapi, rust, gdi

So I'm trying to render the client area of another window onto my own. For this I use the struct

```rust
pub struct Peek {
    id: String,
    target_window: *mut HWND__,
    out_dc: *mut HDC__,
    width: i32,
    height: i32,
}
```

with a method:

```rust
pub fn snap(&mut self) {

    if unsafe { IsWindow(self.target_window) }.is_positive() {
        let mut rect: RECT = RECT::default();
        unsafe { assert!(GetWindowRect(self.target_window, &mut rect).is_positive()) };

        let width = rect.right - rect.left;
        let height = rect.bottom - rect.top;


        if self.height != height || self.width != width {
            self.height = height;
            self.width = width;
            unsafe {

                let screen_dc = GetDC(null_mut());
                assert!(!screen_dc.is_null(), format!("Error getting screen dc: {}",Error::last_os_error()));

                let new_size_bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(screen_dc, self.width,self.height);
                assert!(!new_size_bmp.is_null(), format!("Error creating new bitmap: {}",Error::last_os_error()));

                assert!(ReleaseDC(null_mut(), screen_dc) == 1, format!("Error releasing screen_dc: {}", Error::last_os_error()));

                let ejected_hgdi = SelectObject(self.out_dc, new_size_bmp as HGDIOBJ);
                assert!(!ejected_hgdi.is_null(),format!("Error selecting new size bmp into out_dc: {}",Error::last_os_error()));

                assert!(DeleteObject(ejected_hgdi) != 0,
                        format!("Error deleting old contents of out_dc: {}\nwidth => {}\nheight => {}",
                                Error::last_os_error(), self.width, self.height));
             };


        }


        let target_dc = unsafe { GetDC(self.target_window) };
        assert!(!target_dc.is_null(),
                format!("Error getting dc, (it`s a null): {}",Error::last_os_error()));

        unsafe {assert!(
            BitBlt(self.out_dc,
             0,
             0,
             self.width,
             self.height,
             target_dc,
             rect.left,
             rect.top,
             SRCCOPY).is_positive()
        );}






        unsafe {
            assert!(
                ReleaseDC(self.target_window, target_dc) == 1,
                format!("Error releasing dc: {}",Error::last_os_error())
            )
        };


    } else {
        panic!()
    }
}
```

I've called this method In my window loop like so

```rust
snapper.snap();

unsafe {
        

assert!(StretchBlt (
            dc,
            0,
            0,
            snapper.width,
            snapper.height,
            snapper.out_dc,
            0,
            0,
            snapper.width,
            snapper.height,
            SRCCOPY
        ).is_positive())

};
```

and it works however there is a major display problem I cant pinpoint the origin of. Supposing that the window I want to copy from:

[image: target window]

when I run my script, which generates transparent window and renders the window beneath on it - something like this occur:

[image: the unexpected behavior], the image gets resized in sensible manner - however this black sidelines stay and furthermore I assume are created per iteration of the loop in the snap method as just before that my loop fills the window with white - the transparency colorkey, and calls calls `RedrawWindow`.

What's even more strange is that those black borders expand with the frame but not shrink, so after expanding the target window and shrinking it afterwards the window image does maintain its size but the borders only expand.

I'm not sure if it has to do with the way DC reshapes after the new bitmap is selected into it or with some math fluke, but i was beating my head for a couple of hours on it now - so I'm asking here.

P.S. The crate I use is winapi-rs

Comment: *"I'm trying to render the client area of another window onto my own"* - That's what the [DWM Thumbnail API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/thumbnail-ovw) is for.

Comment: @IInspectable not sure if it actually will be useful in my use case - Yes, right now I want to render it onto the window but that's just for sanity check, as later on I will try to send it to python script as encoded bmp and use open-cv on it.  I'm trying to solve an issue where I want to test object detection from screen footage but displaying the result is interfering with the capture.  I thought of having this overlay rendering the bboxes while the [processing is done on "target_window" frames.